# How to work with 2 models or more?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model

I have done some search here and also on the web but either I'm using wrong keywords or maybe most of the examples on MVVM deal with one model only.

I'm having two models in my project (self learning project on MVVM),  **song** model and **artist** model. So far been able to bind a listview with a collection of information (from song), such that when user clicks on a row on listview information about a song are populated in few textbox controls.

The question I'm facing is that how can I communicate between two models? if we consider a model as a table with its column/fields then I should be able to create a reference to artist model (a foreign key) but what I'm not getting is that how I can retrieve information about an artist when I cilck on his song in the listview?

Long story short, I like to click on a row in listview which showing list of songs and then get its singer/artist pictures, his real name and etc. I'm not following the concept behind how to find related piece of data about an song in artist model.

Any advice will be apprecaited.

this is what I have now:

```
public class Song
{
    string _singerId;
    string _singerName;
    string _songName;
    string _songWriter;
    string _genre; 
    int _songYear; 
    Artist artistReference;
```

Then I have:

```
public class Artist
{

    string _artistBirthName;
    string _artistNationality;
    string _artistImageFile;
    DateTime _artistDateOfBirth;
    DateTime _artistDateOfDeath;
    bool _isArtistAlive;
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is how I provide the information:

Question is how can I insert Artist reference in Song collection?

```
        Artists = new ObservableCollection<Artist>()
        {
            new Artist() { ArtistBirthName = "Francis Albert Sinatra", ArtistNickName = "Ol' Blue Eyes", ArtistNationality = "American", ... },
            new Artist() { ArtistBirthName = "Elvis Aaron Presley", ArtistNickName = "", ArtistNationality = "American", ... },
            new Artist() { ArtistBirthName = "James Paul McCartney", ArtistNickName = "", ArtistNationality = "British", ... },
            new Artist() { ArtistBirthName = "Thomas John Woodward", ArtistNickName = "", ArtistNationality = "British", ... }
        };

        //later read it from xml file or a table.
        Songs = new ObservableCollection<Song>()
        {
            new Song() {ARTIST INFO GOES HERE? HOW?, SingerName = "Fank Sinatra", SongName="Fly me to the Moon", SongWriterName="Bart Howard", Genre="Jazz" ,YearOfRelease= 1980 },
            new Song() {SingerName = "Elvis Presley", SongName="Can't Help Falling in Love", SongWriterName="Paul Anka", Genre="Pop", YearOfRelease= 1969},
            new Song() {SingerName = "The Beatles", SongName="Let It Be", SongWriterName="John Lennon", Genre="Rock", YearOfRelease= 1970},
            new Song() {SingerName = "Tom Jones", SongName="Its Not Unusual", SongWriterName="Les Reed & Gordon Mills", Genre="Pop" , YearOfRelease= 1965}
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm either missing something here or you're just looking for difficulties where there really are none. :) When creating a song object, just pass an artist to it. For example `Artist artist1 = new Artist(...); Song song1 = new Song(..., artist1);`

You'll of course want to define the constructors first.

EDIT: After your edit :)

You can do something like this:

```
 using System.Linq; // For lambda operations

 (...)

 Songs = new ObservableCollection<Song>()
 {
    new Song() {Artist = Artists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Francis Albert Sinatra"), SingerName = ...}
    (...)
 }
```

The  `Artists.FirstOrDefault(...)` part is a LINQ query. It iterates over the `Artists` collection and selects the first item in the collection that matches the condition. If it doesn't find a matching item, it then uses a default value, which should be NULL. It would be better to give each artist a unique ID and search by it instead of name, though, as there can be more artists with the same name. Don't hesitate to ask if you have more questions!

Comment: Maybe but one thing which doesn't click for me is that how a song finds its artist information among all those artists rows? here I'm creating song and artist collections manually for learning purpose; how about in case of getting this information from a source from a web service or xml file?

Comment: I also did edit my question. In the bottom you will see the kind of collection I'm dealing with and like to know how I can add the reference in there. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: now it is making sense. the problem is that I have never used lambda but this should get me going. Thank you I will get back to you soon.

Comment: Try it out, LINQ (Language Integrated Query) is one of the most powerful tools you can find in C#. Don't forget to let me know how it went. :)

Comment: OK, I got a chance to get back to code today and I totally understand the logic behind it but I want do such that when user clicks on a row in listview.  I have changed the models so that Song has two Ids one is SongID and one is ArtistID (foreign key). Of course, Artist model has its own ID which is tied to ArtistID in Song Model. Question is how can I retreive Arist information when a row is clicked while preserving MVVM rules